# H5PY image conversion is corrupted

Tags: python-3.x, h5py

I have been using this code to save my images to h5py files and it has always worked. However, I now have a set of 10K images where the h5py file becomes corrupt for every image converted. I have tried using other images and it works perfectly. To be sure that it was not a problem with the file, I decided to plot it with mat plot lib and it works correctly.

I don't understand, if I plot it there are no problems. I have tried to remove the compression but that is not the problem.

```
 f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(20, 20))
        ax[0].imshow(img)
        ax[0].set_title('Nuova Img')
        ax[1].imshow(gt_mask)
        ax[1].set_title('Vecchia img')
        plt.savefig("my_image.png")
        with h5py.File(os.path.join(output_path, output_fn), "w") as data_h5:
            data_h5.create_dataset("image", data=img, compression="szip")
```

```
This is the script that i use to read the file (the error is below)
 with h5py.File(path1, "r") as data_h5:
        img1 = np.array(data_h5["image"])
        mask1 = np.array(data_h5["mask"])
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Filehdf_reader.py", line 41, in <module>
    main()
  File hdf_reader.py", line 15, in main
    img1 = np.array(data_h5["image"])
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py", line 1063, in __array__
    self.read_direct(arr)
  File "Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py", line 1024, in read_direct
    self.id.read(mspace, fspace, dest, dxpl=self._dxpl)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/h5d.pyx", line 243, in h5py.h5d.DatasetID.read
  File "h5py/_proxy.pyx", line 112, in h5py._proxy.dset_rw
OSError: Can't read data (can't open directory: /usr/local/hdf5/lib/plugin)
```

Comment: I'd focus on making sense of `can't open directory: /usr/local/hdf5/lib/plugin`.  That looks more like a problem with the `hdf5` library, not with a specific data file.

Comment: As I understand it, szip is a plugin. See if gzip works, that is built-in

Comment: As noted by @Homer512, the `szip` filter is not available with all installations of HDF5 (due to legal reasons). What is the error message when you don't use compression? (I suspect it is not about a missing plugin.) Can you create a H5 file with `szip` compression? I don't have `szip` in my h5py installation. Note: recommended way to read a dataset as an array is `img1 = data_h5["image"][()]`.